# Convert units of measurement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, number-formatting

Looking to calculate the most suitable unit of measurement for a list of substances where the substances are given in differing (but compatible) unit volumes.

## Unit Conversion Table

The unit conversion table stores various units and how those units relate:

```
id  unit          coefficient                 parent_id
36  "microlitre"  0.0000000010000000000000000 37
37  "millilitre"  0.0000010000000000000000000 5
 5  "centilitre"  0.0000100000000000000000000 18
18  "decilitre"   0.0001000000000000000000000 34
34  "litre"       0.0010000000000000000000000 19
19  "dekalitre"   0.0100000000000000000000000 29
29  "hectolitre"  0.1000000000000000000000000 33
33  "kilolitre"   1.0000000000000000000000000 35
35  "megalitre"   1000.0000000000000000000000 0
```

Sorting by the coefficient shows that the `parent_id` links a child unit to its numeric superior.

This table can be created in PostgreSQL using:

```
CREATE TABLE unit_conversion (
  id serial NOT NULL, -- Primary key.
  unit text NOT NULL, -- Unit of measurement name.
  coefficient numeric(30,25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- Conversion value.
  parent_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, -- Relates units in order of increasing measurement volume.
  CONSTRAINT pk_unit_conversion PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

There should be a foreign key from `parent_id` to `id`.

## Substance Table

The Substance Table lists specific quantities of substances. For example:

```
 id  unit          label     quantity
 1   "microlitre"  mercury   5
 2   "millilitre"  water     500
 3   "centilitre"  water     2
 4   "microlitre"  mercury   10
 5   "millilitre"  water     600
```

The table might resemble:

```
CREATE TABLE substance (
  id bigserial NOT NULL, -- Uniquely identifies this row.
  unit text NOT NULL, -- Foreign key to unit conversion.
  label text NOT NULL, -- Name of the substance.
  quantity numeric( 10, 4 ) NOT NULL, -- Amount of the substance.
  CONSTRAINT pk_substance PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

## Problem

How would you create a query that finds a measurement to represent the sum of the substances using the fewest digits that has a whole number (and optionally real component)?

For example, how would you return:

```
  quantity  unit        label
        15  microlitre  mercury 
       112  centilitre  water
```

But not:

```
  quantity  unit        label
        15  microlitre  mercury 
      1.12  litre       water
```

Because 112 has fewer real digits than 1.12 and 112 is smaller than 1120. Yet in certain situations using real digits is shorter -- such as 1.1 litres vs 110 centilitres.

Mostly, I'm having troubles picking the correct unit based on the recursive relation.

## Source Code

So far I have (obviously non-working):

```
-- Normalize the quantities
select
  sum( coefficient * quantity ) AS kilolitres
from
  unit_conversion uc,
  substance s
where
  uc.unit = s.unit
group by
  s.label
```

## Ideas

Does this require using log<sub>10</sub> to determine the number of digits?

## Constraints

The units are not all in powers of ten. For example: http://unitsofmeasure.org/ucum-essence.xml

Comment: @mustaccio I had the exact same problem at my previous place, on a very production system. There we had to calculate the amounts used in a food delivery kitchen.

Comment: I remember an at least two level recursive CTE. I think I first calculated the sums with the smallest unit which turned up in the list for the given substance then converted it to the biggest unit still having non-zero integer part.

Comment: Are all units convertible with powers of 10? Is your list of units complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks ugly:

```
  with uu(unit, coefficient, u_ord) as (
    select
     unit, 
     coefficient,
     case 
      when log(u.coefficient) < 0 
      then floor (log(u.coefficient)) 
      else ceil(log(u.coefficient)) 
     end u_ord
    from
     unit_conversion u 
  ),
  norm (label, norm_qty) as (
   select
    s.label,
    sum( uc.coefficient * s.quantity ) AS norm_qty
  from
    unit_conversion uc,
    substance s
  where
    uc.unit = s.unit
  group by
    s.label
  ),
  norm_ord (label, norm_qty, log, ord) as (
   select 
    label,
    norm_qty, 
    log(t.norm_qty) as log,
    case 
     when log(t.norm_qty) < 0 
     then floor(log(t.norm_qty)) 
     else ceil(log(t.norm_qty)) 
    end ord
   from norm t
  )
  select
   norm_ord.label,
   norm_ord.norm_qty,
   norm_ord.norm_qty / uu.coefficient val,
   uu.unit
  from 
   norm_ord,
   uu where uu.u_ord = 
     (select max(uu.u_ord) 
      from uu 
      where mod(norm_ord.norm_qty , uu.coefficient) = 0);
```

but seems to do the trick:

```
|   LABEL | NORM_QTY | VAL |       UNIT |
-----------------------------------------
| mercury |   1.5e-8 |  15 | microlitre |
|   water |  0.00112 | 112 | centilitre |
```

You don't really need the parent-child relationship in the `unit_conversion` table, because the units in the same family are naturally related to each other by the order of `coefficient`, as long as you have the family identified.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this can be largely simplified.

#### 1. Modify `unit_conversion` table

Or, if you cannot modify the table, just add the column `exp10` for "exponent base 10", which coincides with number of digits to shift in the decimal system:

```
CREATE TABLE unit_conversion(
   unit text PRIMARY KEY
  ,exp10 int
);

INSERT INTO unit_conversion VALUES
     ('microlitre', 0)
    ,('millilitre', 3)
    ,('centilitre', 4)
    ,('litre',      6)
    ,('hectolitre', 8)
    ,('kilolitre',  9)
    ,('megalitre',  12)
    ,('decilitre',  5);
```

#### 2. Write function

to calculate the number of positions to shift left or right:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_shift_comma(n numeric)
  RETURNS int LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS
$$
SELECT CASE WHEN ($1 % 1) = 0 THEN                    -- no fractional digits
          CASE WHEN ($1 % 10) = 0 THEN 0              -- no trailing 0, don't shift
          ELSE length(rtrim(trunc($1, 0)::text, '0')) -- trunc() because numeric can be 1.0
                   - length(trunc($1, 0)::text)       -- trailing 0, shift right .. negative
          END
       ELSE                                           -- fractional digits
          length(rtrim(($1 % 1)::text, '0')) - 2      -- shift left .. positive
       END
$$;
```

#### 3. Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (substance_id)
       s.substance_id, s.label, s.quantity, s.unit
      ,COALESCE(s.quantity * 10^(u1.exp10 - u2.exp10)::numeric
              , s.quantity)::float8 AS norm_quantity
      ,COALESCE(u2.unit, s.unit) AS norm_unit
FROM   substance s 
JOIN   unit_conversion u1 USING (unit)
LEFT   JOIN unit_conversion u2 ON f_shift_comma(s.quantity) <> 0
                              AND @(u2.exp10 - (u1.exp10 - f_shift_comma(s.quantity))) < 2
                              -- since maximum gap between exp10 in unit table = 3
                              -- adapt to ceil(to max_gap / 2) if you have bigger gaps
ORDER  BY s.substance_id
     , @(u2.exp10 - (u1.exp10 - f_shift_comma(s.quantity))) -- closest unit first
     , u2.exp10    -- smaller unit first to avoid point for ties.
```

Explain:

- JOIN substance and unit tables.
- Calculate ideal number of positions to shift with function `f_shift_comma()` from above.
- LEFT JOIN to the unit table a second time to find units close to the optimum.
- Pick the closest unit with `DISTINCT ON ()` and `ORDER BY`.
- If no better unit is found, fall back to what we had with `COALESCE()`.
- This should cover all corner cases and be *pretty fast*.

[-> **SQLfiddle** demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/29137/1)

Comment: @DaveJarvis: And there I thought I had covered everything ... this detail would have been real helpful in the otherwise carefully crafted question.